# How to rollback service when in-app purchase in AppStore was redeemed by customer

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app

It is a question I searched from web but there isn't any question.But I think it's a common question.
I have an application which support In-app purchases. My server will check receipt when customer bought it and then enable service. But later customer redeemed the purchases,but my server can't get informed and still serve them. Apple's store kit never mention it and can't find any clue from stackoverflow and web.
Is there any clue for it?

Thanks in advance